# How to add foreign key in SQL Server in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I want to know how to add a foreign key into my website through the payment section which is I created a list Seminar for user to choose first including a schedule. After that, user can click register and redirect page into payment details form which is contains credit card or cash. after user make an payment and click confirm button then the database should be increase by one include the primary key of an id (auto generate).

My problem is why I am still getting an id which is -1 not even +1 (I checked,  the database has not updated in SQL Server) because of an id is -1.

Here is my code regarding for the payment section

```
if (tbxName.Text != null && tbxCC.Text != null && ddlCCType.Text != null && tbxExpDate.Text != null)
{
        ShoppingCart sc = (ShoppingCart)Session["cart"];
        sc.Name = tbxName.Text;

        if (rdbCash.Checked == true)
        {
            sc.OptionPay = rdbCash.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            sc.OptionPay = rdbCC.Text;
        }

        sc.CreditCard = tbxCC.Text;
        sc.CreditCardType = ddlCCType.Text;
        sc.SecurityCode = tbxCode.Text;
        sc.CCExpiryDate = tbxExpDate.Text;
        //sc.Registration.RegId = sc.Id;

        int id = ShoppingCartDBMgr.purchaseSeminar(sc);

        lblOutput.Text = "Confirm. order id is " + id;
        //display output for payment successfully
        //lblOutput.Text = "Payment Successfully!";
        //make it null for amount, date and session of cart after transaction are being successful
        lblAmount.Text = null;
        lblDate.Text = null;
        Session["cart"] = null;
```

My payment database manager code:

```
public static int purchaseSeminar(ShoppingCart sc)
{
    int id = -1;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);

    try
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = con;
        command.CommandText = "insert into Payment (payment_id, payment_name, payment_ccNo, payment_ccType, payment_ccCode, payment_expDate, payment_price, payment_optionPay, payment_date, reg_id) values (@payment_id, @payment_name, @payment_ccNo, @payment_ccType, @payment_ccCode, @payment_expDate, @payment_price, @payment_optionPay, @payment_date, @reg_id)";
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_id", sc.Id);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_ccNo", sc.CreditCard);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_ccType", sc.CreditCardType);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_ccCode", sc.SecurityCode);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_expDate", sc.CCExpiryDate);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_price", sc.TotalAmount);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_optionPay", sc.OptionPay);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg_id", sc.Registration.RegId);

        DateTime da = DateTime.Now;
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_date", da);

        con.Open();

        command.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Payment ON";

        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
        {
            command.CommandText = "Select @@identity";
            id = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
        }

        return id;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you never execute the insert, you only execute “set identity_insert...”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where sc.Id is being assigned a value unlike the others(eg: sc.Name). Then inserting that(sc.Id) into the database will insert a null value. So when you query it from the database, converting it to an int32 value, returns '-1'.

That's what I think might be causing the problem along with the structure of your code.

Since your id is auto-generated, exclude the 'payment_ID' from your insert command. Example:

```
command.CommandText = "insert into Payment (payment_name, payment_ccNo, 
                       payment_ccType, payment_ccCode, payment_expDate, payment_price, 
                       payment_optionPay, payment_date, reg_id) 
                values (@payment_name, @payment_ccNo, @payment_ccType, @payment_ccCode, 
                        @payment_expDate, @payment_price, @payment_optionPay, 
                        @payment_date, @reg_id)";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_ccNo", sc.CreditCard);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_ccType", sc.CreditCardType);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_ccType", sc.CreditCardType);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_ccCode", sc.SecurityCode);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_expDate", sc.CCExpiryDate);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_price", sc.TotalAmount);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_optionPay", sc.OptionPay);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg_id", sc.Registration.RegId);
```

As an identity column, 'payment_ID' doesn't expect a value so exclude it from your insert statement. That way, you won't need to turn IDENTITY INSERT on. So you'll remove those statements too from your code.

Comment: id is auto generate, so the user cannot an id.

Comment: Then you shouldn't have an input for that column. Let me give you a sample code I worked on -
  new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Photo VALUES (@StaffId,@StaffPhoto,@Fingerprint)",sql);                                                        Here, PhotoId is a primary key that is auto-generated so I didn't include it in the insert command. Do same to yours and you wouldn't need to turn the IDENTITY INSERT on.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good way of doing it however for your answer 
you should add

This should be on your first line

```
command.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Payment On"; 

command.CommandText = "insert into Payment (payment_id, payment_name, payment_ccNo, payment_ccType, payment_ccCode, payment_expDate, payment_price, payment_optionPay, payment_date, reg_id) values (@payment_id, @payment_name, @payment_ccNo, @payment_ccType, @payment_ccCode, @payment_expDate, @payment_price, @payment_optionPay, @payment_date, @reg_id)";

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_id", sc.Id);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_ccNo", sc.CreditCard);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_ccType", sc.CreditCardType);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_ccCode", sc.SecurityCode);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_expDate", sc.CCExpiryDate);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_price", sc.TotalAmount);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment_optionPay", sc.OptionPay);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg_id", sc.Registration.RegId);
```

And this should be your last line

```
command.CommandText = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT Payment OFF";
```

Comment: ok, i edit my code already to set an identity on at the first line and off should be on the last line, thanks